# Assigning input to variable

Tags: forms, settings-api, wp-create-user

I am trying to create a plugin that will generate users. I am pretty new to Wordpress and my PHP is ehhhh. I got some helpful help earlier but have made a few turns since...

The plugin will generate a user when submit it clicked, the issue is it ignores anything put into the input field and doesn't require it to work. Even if I set $num_users to a number it still only generates one...Perhaps an issue with my for loop?

I know it has to be something small I am over looking.

```
 function sl_add_options_page() {
    // Add new page under the "Settings tab
    add_options_page(
        __( 'User Options' ),
        __( 'User Options' ),
        'manage_options',
        'user_options_page',
        'sl_render_options_page'
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sl_add_options_page' );

function sl_render_options_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php _e( 'Content & User Generator Options' ); ?></h2>
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php settings_fields( 'num_users' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'user_options_page' ); ?>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Submit' ); ?>">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function sl_add_setting() {
    // Register a binary value called "pimple_disable"
    register_setting(
        'num_users',
        'num_users',
        'absint'
    );

    // Add the settings section to hold the interface
    add_settings_section(
        'user_main_settings',
        __( 'User Controls' ),
        'sl_render_main_settings_section',
        'user_options_page'
    );

    // Add the settings field to define the interface
    add_settings_field(
        'user_main_settings_field',
        __( 'How Many users' ),
        'sl_render_users_input',
        'user_options_page',
        'user_main_settings'
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'sl_add_setting' );

function randomName() {
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $name = array(); 
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $name[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($name); 
}


function randomEmail() {
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $email = array(); 
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $email[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($email);
}

function sl_wp_create_user() {
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        //$num_users = 100;
        $num_users = $_POST['num_users'];
        for( $j = 0; $j <= $num_users; $j++ ) { 
        $username = randomName();
        $email = randomEmail() . '@gmail.com';
        $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );

            $user_login = esc_sql( $username );
            $user_email = esc_sql( $email    );
            $user_pass = esc_sql( $password );

            $userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass');
            return wp_insert_user($userdata);
        } 
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'sl_wp_create_user' );

function sl_render_main_settings_section() {
    echo '<p>Main settings for the Content and User Generator plugin.</p>';
}

function sl_render_users_input() {
    echo '<input id="num_users" name="num_users[]" type="text" value=""/>';
}
```

Comment: What `for` loop? I only see two and both create random strings, not insert users. Also, you are inserting users every time `$_POST['submit']`  is set. That could be a lot. Why are you using such a generic trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't contain the fields you think it does.

Use FireBug or a similar tool (even var_dump($_POST)) to see what is actually being posted.

Your num_users is a setting group, not a single field. At best the field with the value will be user_main_settings field.

The previous commenter is also correct - checking for $_POST['submit'] as your trigger is dangerous.

Have a look at this tutorial: http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/